# Statement violates GTID consistency error when creatng new user account in Drupal

Tags: drupal, user-account

I’m running CiviCRM 5.16.2 against Drupal 7.67 on 1&1 Ionos hosting. MySQL version is 5.7.27.

When I create a new account in Drupal via the “Create New Account” button on the login screen, once I’ve completed all the fields and press “Create new account”, I get a yellow panel with the following error.

```
Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred. 
DB Error: unknown error
```

Then this in the white section underneath:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Transaction integrity error: Expected to find active frame thrown in /xxxxxxxx/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/Transaction/Manager.php on line 107
```

The user account appears to have been created when I go to the People section in Drupal. I have tried this on a completely fresh installation/database and the same thing happenes.
I’ve turned on debugging and have got the following further info…

```
Database Error Code: Statement violates GTID consistency: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE and DROP TEMPORARY TABLE can only be executed outside transactional context. These statements are also not allowed in a function or trigger because functions and triggers are also considered to be multi-statement transactions., 1787
Additional Details: 
Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => handle
        )

    [code] => -1
    [message] => DB Error: unknown error
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] => CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `civicrm_tmp_e_dedupe_97911c832652885b9b1c932dfbe6530d` (id1 int, weight int, UNIQUE UI_id1 (id1)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci [nativecode=1787 ** Statement violates GTID consistency: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE and DROP TEMPORARY TABLE can only be executed outside transactional context.  These statements are also not allowed in a function or trigger because functions and triggers are also considered to be multi-statement transactions.]
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] => CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `civicrm_tmp_e_dedupe_97911c832652885b9b1c932dfbe6530d` (id1 int, weight int, UNIQUE UI_id1 (id1)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci [nativecode=1787 ** Statement violates GTID consistency: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE and DROP TEMPORARY TABLE can only be executed outside transactional context.  These statements are also not allowed in a function or trigger because functions and triggers are also considered to be multi-statement transactions.]
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: unknown error" code=-1 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info="CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `civicrm_tmp_e_dedupe_97911c832652885b9b1c932dfbe6530d` (id1 int, weight int, UNIQUE UI_id1 (id1)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci [nativecode=1787 ** Statement violates GTID consistency: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE and DROP TEMPORARY TABLE can only be executed outside transactional context.  These statements are also not allowed in a function or trigger because functions and triggers are also considered to be multi-statement transactions.]"]
)
```

What is causing this and how do I go about solving it?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This came up before at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/cloud-native/issues/9. You might want to ask in there.